# How to compare a set of data to another data in a different sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to know how to compare or know the data to another data in a different sheet in Excel 2007.

Example:

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

How can I compare the data whether it is the same and show in Sheet 3?

Answer (score 0):

to find out if its in the same cell you can use:

```
=Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1
```

it will display true if A1 in both sheets is the same.  you can place that formula in cell A1 on sheet3 and copy it down and to the right as needed.